# Unable to use OpenLayer

Tags: web, openlayers

I'm very new with web language and I have to integrate a map in a page. I'm using cshtml with Visual Studio 2015

To do this I have take a code using `ol.js`. The map have to be displayed, and for each value in my table I localize the city/country from IP and I display for each countries, the number of item.

There is my Index.cshtml

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var map;
    var countriesLayer;
    var citiesLayer;

    function newCountriesLayer(start, end, item, result) {
        return new ol.layer.Vector({
            minResolution: 2500,
            source: new ol.source.GeoJSON({
                projection: 'EPSG:3857',
                url: '@Url.Action("GetCountries")'
                    + '?StartDate=' + start
                    + '&EndDate=' + end
                    + '&Item=' + item
                    + '&Result=' + result
            }),
            style: function (f, r) {
                return [
                    new ol.style.Style({
                        text: new ol.style.Text({ text: f.get("title"), fill: new ol.style.Fill({ color: '#673B8F' }), scale: 1.2 }),
                        image: new ol.style.Circle({ radius: 10, fill: new ol.style.Fill({ color: 'white' }) }),
                    })
                ];
            }
        });
    }

    function newCitiesLayer(start, end, item, result) {
        return new ol.layer.Vector({
            maxResolution: 2500,
            source: new ol.source.GeoJSON({
                projection: 'EPSG:3857',
                url: '@Url.Action("GetCities")'
                    + '?StartDate=' + start
                    + '&EndDate=' + end
                    + '&Item=' + item
                    + '&Result=' + result
            }),
            style: function (f, r) {
                return [
                    new ol.style.Style({
                        text: new ol.style.Text({ text: f.get("title"), fill: new ol.style.Fill({ color: '#673B8F' }), scale: 1.2 }),
                        image: new ol.style.Circle({ radius: 10, fill: new ol.style.Fill({ color: 'white' }) }),
                    })
                ];
            }
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var start = $('#startDate').val();
        var end = $('#endDate').val();
        var item = $('#item').val();
        var result = $('#resultat').val();

        countriesLayer = newCountriesLayer(start, end, item, result);
        citiesLayer = newCitiesLayer(start, end, item, result);

        map = new ol.Map({
            target: 'map',
            renderer: 'canvas',
            layers:
            [
                new ol.layer.Tile({
                    //source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
                    //    url: 'http://maps.opengeo.org/geowebcache/service/wms',
                    //    params: { LAYERS: 'openstreetmap', VERSION: '1.1.1' }
                    //})
                    source: new ol.source.OSM(),
                }),
                countriesLayer, citiesLayer
            ],
            view: new ol.View2D({
                center: ol.proj.transform([0, 0], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
                zoom: 1,
            })
        });
    });
</script>
```

In my Controller.cs I have 2 functions:

```
public ContentResult GetCities(string StartDate, string EndDate, string Item, string Result){...}

public ContentResult GetCountries(string StartDate, string EndDate, string Item, string Result){...}
```

both return :

```
return new ContentResult()
{
    Content = geoJson.ToString(),
    ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII,
    ContentType = "text/json"
};
```

Value for geoJson is :

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "crs": { 
        "type": "name",
        "properties": { 
            "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" 
        } 
    },
    "features": [
    { 
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "id":"CN-30-Guangzhou",
            "title":"2",
        }, 
        "geometry": { 
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [113.25,23.1167]
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": { 
            "id":"CN-23-Shanghai", 
            "title":"1",
        },
        "geometry": { 
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [121.3997,31.0456] 
        }
    },
]}
```

In the project that I took this code, it works. The map contain 2 points in china : a "1" is displayed in Shanghai and a "2" in Guangzhou.

In my project I have an error :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'a' of null
>
> ```
> at xl (ol.js:266)
> at wl (ol.js:265)
> at Bl (ol.js:268)
> at Al (ol.js:269)
> at nr (ol.js:471)
> at pr.mr.f (ol.js:470)
> at td (ol.js:38)
> at N (ol.js:37)
> at Xq.q (ol.js:467)
> ```

As I said, I'm very new to web and I lost with that error. If try to check ol.js but it is unreadable. Maybe I'm missing a library or a package but I don't know how to know.

Comment: Get used to that. OL errors in lot of cases really suck and don't help in any way. These errors usually mean that some values passed are not in the correct data type, form etc. Check what you pass, try w/ some static values...

Comment: First of all, please use a recent version of OpenLayers, i.e. 4.0.x. Note that there is no `ol.source.GeoJSON` any more. Use `ol.source.Vector` with an `ol.format.GeoJSON` any more. To get a more readable stack trace, use `ol-debug.js` instead of `ol.js`.

Comment: I've try with debug but it did nit work. I finally find what the problem was : my coordinates was given with `,` instead of `.`. I wasted 3 days for that...